# Finding available rooms from datespan

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a start date and a end date.

```
 $s="YYYY-MM-DD";
 $e="YYYY-MM-DD";
```

I need to make a query that checks the available rooms for that span.

```
 cObjects , cBookings_details
 cObjects_id = cBookings_details_cObjects_id
```

Im really stuck here, would really appreciate some help.

My Current Query

```
 SELECT cObjects.*
FROM cObjects LEFT JOIN cBookings_details ON cObjects.cObjects_id = cBookings_details.cBookings_details_cObjects_id
WHERE cBookings_details.cBookings_details_arrival NOT BETWEEN '".$s."' AND '".$e."' 
AND cBookings_details.cBookings_details_departure NOT BETWEEN '".$s."' AND '".$e."' 
AND cBookings_details.cBookings_details_arrival <> '".$s."' AND cBookings_details_departure <> '".$s."'
AND cBookings_details.cBookings_details_arrival <> '".$e."' AND cBookings_details_departure <> '".$e."'
AND cObjects.cObjects_type < '2'

OR cBookings_details.cBookings_details_id is null AND cObjects_type < '2'
```

Comment: You really haven't given us much to go on, [How to ask a **good** question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you're mixing `or` and `and` without any `()` to enforce parsing order. Fix that first and see if the query starts behaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem.. actually just wrote a guide for this at work:

```
Selecting rows with start and end dates that feature in a chosen interval 
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Chosen Interval -  :start_date    (S) 
                   :end_date      (E)

Rows            -  row.start_date (s)
                   row.end_date   (e)

Increasing date-->

         S       E
         |       |           Chosen Interval 

1.     s---e                 Rows we want
2.        s---e                    .
3.            s---e                .
4.     s----------e                .

5.  s--e                     Rows we don't want
6.                s--e             .

LOGIC:
row.end_date >= :start_date AND row.start_date <= :end_date
```

If you are looking for available rooms, `LEFT JOIN` the room to the bookings using the logic above and `SELECT` rows where the booking is `NULL`.

Applied to your schema I believe this would come out as:

```
   SELECT o.*
     FROM cObjects o 
LEFT JOIN cBookings_details bd
       ON bd.cBookings_details_cObjects_id = o.cObjects_id
      AND bd.cBookings_details_arrival <= :end_date
      AND bd.cBookings_details_departure >= :start_date 
    WHERE bd.cBookings_details_id IS NULL
     (AND o.cObjects_type < '2') # Double check this is what you want
```

By the way, I would cry if I had to work with your schema. Why repeat the table name in the column? It just adds noise.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! The only thing is that if there is a check-out at 2015-08-20 i need to be able to book in another guest the same day for checkin. Could i solve that by simply replacing <= and >= with < and > removing the equalsigns ? @Arth

Comment: @Martin No problem, happy to help! Think of it logically, you are selecting bookings that clash and then discounting the relevant rooms. Is it a clash if their is an arrival on the end date? No? Then remove the `=` from `AND bd.cBookings_details_arrival <= :end_date`. Is it a problem if there is a departure on the start date? No? Then remove the other `=` from `bd.cBookings_details_departure >= :start_date`. And then test it!